# OpenGL bible 5th edition code problems

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I have seen 2 posts with this same question but one was with visual studio and the other didn't work so here goes. i am attempting to compile the first source code that comes with the opening bible 5th edition...but i am trying to do so with the code::blocks ide.
i thought i had freeglut installed correctly(as i can run the glut program that comes with C::B) but i am getting numerous errors from glut and glu...and after i thought i fixed those problems now im getting over 50 error and i have no idea what is causing them.
the error look like this

```
obj\Debug\main.o(.text+0x2eb):C:\Users|20|undefined reference to `GLShaderManager::~GLShaderManager()'|
```

`C:\Users\t\main.cpp|27|undefined reference to`glViewport@16'|`

all the error are very similar but the undefined reference changes to another OpenGL function.

any help would be appreciated and just ask if you need the source code or more error.

**EDIT**
after adding glu32 to the linker it got rid of all error regarding that
but there appear to be a problem with my freeglut installation i am getting error

```
obj\Debug\main.o(.text+0x1c)||In function `glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK':|

freeglut_std.h|610|undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'|

obj\Debug\main.o(.text+0x3f)||In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':|

freeglut_std.h|612|undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'|

obj\Debug\main.o(.text+0x61)||In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':|

freeglut_std.h|614|undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'|
```

solved free glut problem...i had to use different library files.... i got them from [here](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)

**Edit 2**
i got freeglut working by now the custom library that the book used is giving me an error...i belive this is becouse i am attempting to use a .lib file (which is what it came as) this might have been the source of all my errors...can C::B link .lib files or does it only take .a and .o files for library?

Comment: .lib files are for Visual Studio. C::B uses MinGW (=gcc) and needs .a files. If you don't have the .a file for whatever lib you want to use, you have to rebuild it yourselft, using C::B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add proper libraries to link against with.

For C::B,

- Go to Project
- Select Build Option
- Select Linkers
- Add OpenGL, Glu32 libraries to your project.

Response to your EDIT:

Follow the steps in here: http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~goetz/codeblocks/glut/

Comment: were are the glu32 libraries located ?

Comment: lol... i have followed this tutorial...i even refered to in in one of my other posts...but this doesn't help with getting freeglut working...as it is completely different for some reason :(

Comment: Did you install Freeglut on your system first? If you did, show C::B the path to *.lib files. That should solve all your problems.

Comment: ...this is really annoying in 2 seconds i got these external library working in visual studio...i wish it was that easy in code blocks...